# Image popup when hovering a text div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a preview of sheet music listed on an ordered list. I can only get to display the image when hovering on the < li > element, but I would like to only see the image when hovering on the first section of each row ("[ view ]"). I've tried modifying different things, but I can't get it right. This is how my experiment looks so far: http://www.antonioromo.com/newsite/music.html

I'm sure I have redundant code and that I probably just need to change something simple, but I'm no expert.

This is the way I'm listing items:

```
<div id="SheetMusicStore">
  <ol class="enlarge">
    <li>
      <span class="view">[ view ]</span>
      <span class="preview"><img src="images/01gnw-tn.png" alt="Just Another Dusk" /><br />Just Another Dusk (Good Night Wishes)</span>
      <span class="name">Just Another Dusk (Good Night Wishes)</span>
      <span class="price">$3.99 BUY</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="view">[ view ]</span>
      <span class="preview"><img src="images/02gnw-tn.png" alt="My Nightlight" /><br />My Nightlight (Good Night Wishes)</span>
      <span class="name">My Nightlight (Good Night Wishes)</span>
      <span class="price">$3.99 BUY</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
/** Sheet Music Store **/
#SheetMusicStore {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
ol.enlarge{
  margin-left:0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #999;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #582E58;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #582E58;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #582E58;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  background: url(../images/sheet-bg.png) repeat 0 0 scroll;
  color: #AAA;
}
ol.enlarge li{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; /*resets the stack order of the list items - later we'll increase this*/
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  background: transparent url(../images/sheet-item-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left scroll;
  padding: 5px 0 7px 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ol.enlarge img{
  background-color: #eae9d4;
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
ol.enlarge span.preview{
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  background-color: #eae9d4;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #495a62;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75));
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
ol.enlarge li:hover{
  color: #EEE;
  z-index: 50;
}
ol.enlarge li:hover .view{
  color:#FFFFCC !important;
}
ol.enlarge .view:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
ol.enlarge span.preview img{
  padding: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
ol.enlarge li:hover span.preview{
  top: -300px; /*the distance from the bottom of the thumbnail to the top of the popup image*/
  left: 300px; /*distance from the left of the thumbnail to the left of the popup image*/
  z-index: 50;
}
ol.enlarge .price {
  width: 62px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  background: transparent url(../images/buy-bg.png) repeat 0 0 scroll;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #BBB;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 0;
}
ol.enlarge .price:hover {
  color: #EEE;
}
```

Also, I don't know why there is a large blank space left at the very bottom of the page. Is it created by the elements created on the fly? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Generally, change `li:hover` to `span.view:hover` and `li:hover span.preview` to `span.view:hover ~ span.preview`. It would be easier if you can provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so people can actually change your code and show it to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fiddle suggestion. I didn't even know that existed! I stopped developing websites about 5 years ago and now it's a different world! :) I tried your suggestion which is the same as Martin's below, but it still doesn't work. I don't know what the heck I am doing wrong. :/

Comment: Well my suggestion is not exactly the same as Martin's, but the logics are similar. I checked your link, and, still the problem is I can't change your style to test. I still suggest you to make a fiddle _yourself_. Not only will that provides convenience for people, but there's also chances that, upon making your own fiddle, you finally/accidently found out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, Passerby. Martin got me unstuck. I'll have to experiment with those fiddles if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest the `preview` inside the `view` element. And just change the

```
ol.enlarge li:hover span.preview
```

to something like

```
span.view:hover span.preview
```

here is a [demo on **jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6aU2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, Martin. I checked it at jsfiddle and I saw it working, but for some reason I can't make it work locally or in my temporary site. I even tried copying and pasting and it still didn't work. I left your solution in the same link (http://www.antonioromo.com/newsite/music.html) to show you how it looks now. Same as yesterday, but now the images don't show. I know they're there because all I changed was the code. Thanks again for your assistance and patience.

Comment: you have to make sure you include the `preview` element in the `view` ... if this is not clear enough ... it needs to be: `<span class="view">[view]<span class="preview">image and caption</span></span>` or use this selector in CSS: `span.view:hover ~ span.preview`

Comment: Just to inform you, since you are new on stack overflow ... you can show appreciation for an working answer to your question by checking it as accepted/solved.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I wouldn't have noticed. :)